# About injective and projective tensor products of commutative Banach algebras

Tags: tensor-products, banach-algebras

Let $A_i$, $B_i$, $i=1,2$, be semisimple commutative Banach algebras such that $A_i$ is isomorphic to $B_i$, $i=1,2$. Is the injective tensor product of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is isomorphic to the injective tensor product of $B_1$ and $B_2$? What about the projective tensor product?

Comment: Yes. Tensoring the isomorphisms gives you an isomorphism of Banach spaces between the two completed tensor products. Then you can check directly that this map between the two completed tensor products is an algebra homomorphism, just by checking on elementary tensors and extending by linearity and continuity.